# Rails automatically adds ".csv" to download name for format CSV, but not for others (e.g. ".xlsx")

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users can download data from my Rails project in CSV or XLSX format.

Here's the action:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xlsx { render xlsx: 'index', filename: filename_for_export(@project, export_type, :xlsx) }
    format.csv { render csv: collection, filename: filename_for_export(@project, export_type, :csv) }
  end
end

private

    def filename_for_export(project, type, format)
  "#{project.customer} - #{project.name} (#{type}, #{t 'org.name'}, #{Date.today.to_s :db}).#{format}"
end
```

Interestingly, when opening `.csv`, Rails seems to add `.csv` again to the filename (which already has the format in it).

[image]

When opening `.xlsx`, this doesn't happen:

[image]

Interestingly, when removing the file extension from the generated name, then both have one single correct extension, although XLSX shouldn't have any extension now (in my opinion).

Comment: Not sure that's a rails thing.  Have you tested to make verify if this is a mac downloads issue?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are forcing the extension out for `xlsx` files by using `render xlsx: 'index'`.

If you change that line to `render xlsx: 'index.xlsx'`, you should get a consistent behavior. I imagine that you won't have to set the extension in `filename_for_export` anymore.